# NuGet restore stopped working inside Docker Container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, nuget

When I try to run `dotnet restore` as a `RUN` instruction of a `Dockerfile` while building it, I get the following errors:

```
/src/Anonymized.Tests/Anonymized.Tests.csproj : error NU3028: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature's timestamp found a chain building issue: UntrustedRoot: self signed certificate in certificate chain [/src/Anonymized.sln]
/src/Anonymized.Tests/Anonymized.Tests.csproj : error NU3037: Package 'Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents 5.0.0' from source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json': The author primary signature validity period has expired. [/src/Anonymized.sln]
```

It happens for all of my NuGet packages.

If I run it outside the container, it works just fine.

I am using the image `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0`. Could it be that the Docker image I am running it in has expired certificates somehow?

It worked until a couple of hours back.

**Edit:** Not sure if it's important information, but this is all running from GitHub Actions, in Linux.

Comment: Same problem here.
`dotnet restore` outside docker works just fine.
`dotnet restore` inside docker presents me for every package with exactly the same error you described for every package.

Comment: @Jejuni thank you for sharing that with me. Do you have any idea of who to contact from here? Are you also running things within GitHub Actions and Docker? Can you share more on your specific case?

Comment: Sadly so far no idea.
Happens from my home machine (no proxy, no nothing) as well as company network.
I'm running my own pipeline in Azure DevOps and using our own company build server. But when I manually invoke `docker-compose build` it happens locally as well as build server.
Downloading a mentioned package manually in docker and running `dotnet nuget verify --all some.package.nupkg` also complains about UntrustedRoot. Outside docker the command completes without error.

Comment: Alright. Let's keep each other posted if we figure out the root cause, shall we? Thanks once again.

Comment: Watch https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

Solution 1:

As mentioned on github, if your Dockerfile looks similar to this:
`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0` change it to

- `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-alpine`, or
- `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal`

Solution 2:

Add this to your Dockerfile before running restore:

```
RUN curl -o /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/verisign.crt -SsL https://crt.sh/?d=1039083 && update-ca-certificates
```

For security reasons you may want to download & verify the certificate and save it to your repo.
This is the certificate necessary to validate the timestamp of the packages and it's included by default in alpine and focal, but is missing from debian.

Solution 3:

Wait for Microsoft to fix the problem.
They're tracking it on github and Nuget has set it's status to degraded until the problem is solved: https://status.nuget.org/

Original answer:

From what I can tell Docker is right in this case.
Download any NuGet package manually, ie: https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/System.ComponentModel.Annotations/5.0.0
Open the file and look for the .signature.p7s file and open it with the default program.
It shows me that there is a certificate by Microsoft that expired literally today at 1 PM local time.

[image: Certificates]

I have no idea why this isn't a problem for the tooling outside of docker.
I know there's a way to completely disable NuGet's verification explained here along with some more information about the validity period:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3028
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu3037

I don't really want to completely disable the checks though.
Sadly I also don't know how to proceed in this case

Comment: Watch https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates

Answer (score 2):

At the moment the issue appears to be related to the Debian image.

Switch to an Ubuntu based image instead:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-focal
```

Follow https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/10491 for updates.

Comment: Was about to post this.
Can confirm that solved my problem for now.
Thankfully we're using yaml pipelines and changing out pipeline/Dockerfile back and forth is hassle free, so we'll be chaning to focal until MS sort their certificate / image out and then we might switch back